# Bootstrap Multiselect - unselect by onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, select, multi-select

I'm using the **Bootstrap-Multiselect** function; I want to unselect an option when I click on "x".
This is a simple example of what I'm looking for.

```js
$(document).on("click", '#remove', function(a) {
  var tag = this.getAttribute("value");

  $('#tags').find('[value=' + tag + ']').prop('selected', false);
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.7.5/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.7.5/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Bootstrap Select demo</h1>
    <select class="selectpicker" id='Tags' data-style="btn-primary" multiple data-max-options="2">
      <option value='Php' selected>PHP</option>
      <option>CSS</option>
      <option>HTML</option>
      <option>CSS 3</option>
      <option>Bootstrap</option>
      <option>JavaScript</option>
    </select>

    <div value='Php' id='remove'>x</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be achieved by unselecting all then getting the selected values and remove the target tag from them and reselect the rest of them then finally refresh the select :

```js
$(document).on("click", '#remove', function(a) {
  var tag = this.getAttribute("value");
  var values = $('#tags').val();
  
  if(values){
  $('#tags').selectpicker('deselectAll');
  $('#tags').selectpicker('val', values.filter(function(e) {return e !== tag }));
  $('#tags').selectpicker('refresh');
  }
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.7.5/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.7.5/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Bootstrap Select demo</h1>
    <select class="selectpicker" id='tags' data-style="btn-primary" multiple data-max-options="2">
      <option value='Php' selected>PHP</option>
      <option>CSS</option>
      <option>HTML</option>
      <option>CSS 3</option>
      <option>Bootstrap</option>
      <option>JavaScript</option>
    </select>

    <div value='Php' id='remove'>x</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Congratulations Chrissy, you've earned the **[VoteUp privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)** consider to use it, if any answer from the posted here is what you're looking for Mark it as the **[correct answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)**.

Comment: Thanks @sudharshan-nair for your intervention

Comment: You made my day! Thank you very much for your help! :D

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki. Welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should not use the value attribute in a div element, since it was not designed the job you are trying to do ([see here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_value.asp)). You can use a data-tag="php" for example, and when writing html I think is best to use " instead of ' too, but the browser do the trick.
In the select element, you wrote the id tags with the first letter in "caps lock"
 and then in the javascript code you use #tags, see:

```
<select class="selectpicker" id='Tags' data-style="btn-primary" multiple data-max-options="2">
$('#tags').find('[value=' + tag + ']').prop('selected', false);
```

After that, you just need to remove the selected element from the array and set the values again, see a working example:

```js
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $(document).on("click", '#remove', function(a) {
      var removed = $(this).data('value')
      var values = $("#tags").val()
      var index = values.indexOf(removed)
      if (index != -1) {
        values.splice(index, 1)
        $('#tags').selectpicker('val', values);
      } 
    });
  });
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.7.5/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.7.5/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Bootstrap Select demo</h1>
    <select class="selectpicker" id="tags" data-style="btn-primary" multiple data-max-options="2">
      <option value="Php" selected>PHP</option>
      <option>CSS</option>
      <option>HTML</option>
      <option>CSS 3</option>
      <option>Bootstrap</option>
      <option>JavaScript</option>
    </select>

    <div data-value="Php" id="remove">x</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```